# Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty}\dfrac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}=\infty$ by the definition.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

## Problem

Prove $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty}\dfrac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}=\infty$ by the definition.

#### Note:

The problem asks us to prove that, no matter $x \to +\infty$ or $x \to -\infty$, the limit is $\infty$,which may be $+\infty$ or $-\infty.$

## Proof

$\forall M>0$,$\exists X=\max(1,M+1)>0, \forall|x|>X$：
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}\right|&=\left|x-\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}\right|\\&\geq |x|-\left|\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}\right|\\&\geq |x|-\frac{|x|+1}{x^2+1}\\&\geq |x|-\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+1}\\&=|x|-1\\&>X-1\\&\geq M.
\end{align*}

**Please verify the proof above.**

Comment: It's basically correct, but I dislike how you've written it.

Comment: Your inequalities look fine, but, your setup is fishy. For example, there should be no absolute value signs around the $x$. Also, the expression with the existential quantifier $\exists X$ is part of the *statement you are proving*, whereas the assigned value $X = \text{Max}(1,M+1)$ is part of the *proof that $X$ exists*. Mixing up the statement and the proof, as you have done, is a bad idea.

Comment: @LeeMosher We should consider $|x|$,not $x$, because the limit is under the process $x \to \infty$ not $x \to +\infty.$

Comment: The default meaning, in all sources that I know (and in how I teach) is that $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ is like $\lim_{x \to 1}$ in that we suppress writing the $+$ sign, *even though* our intention is $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$ or $\lim_{x \to +1}$.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have seen that usage in complex variables courses before, or something like it. If it's tagged `real-analysis`, maybe they're using something closer to the one-point compactification of the reals for their infinity? Dunno which author does that though, and I agree that it's super non-standard.

Comment: In China's teaching for calculus, especially in Chinese textbooks,$x \to \infty$ implies $x \to +\infty$ AND $x \to -\infty.$ But $n \to \infty$ only implies $n \to +\infty$, because that notation is for sequence limit only.

Comment: @mengdie1982 That's a fun communication barrier I wouldn't have expected. Thank you for the clarification. Since many users (the bulk of users probably -- given the answers you've already received) of this site have an alternate interpretation of that notation, would you mind adding that detail to your question? I think it'll prevent a lot of responses like the non-applicable answers you've seen.

Comment: @HansMusgrave OK！ I accept your advice. THX.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct.

You may consider shorter proofs by using some simplifications.

Since $x\to \infty $ we assume $x>1$

$$ \frac {x^3+1}{x^2+1} \ge\frac {x^3}{2x^2}=x/2$$

Comment: Your inequality goes in the wrong direction for the statement being proved.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it to the right direction

Comment: Wait! $|x|\geq1$ does not imply $|x^3+1| \geq |x^3|.$ You may have $|x^3+1|\geq |x^3|-1.$

Comment: But，thus，you also need to consider $x<0$...

Comment: Thanks. I had positive $x$ values in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks ok to me.

An option:

$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1);$

$x^2+1<x^2+x =x(x+1)$, for $x >1$.

$\dfrac{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}{x^2+1}>$

$\dfrac{(x+1)(x^2-x+1)}{x(x+1)}=$

$x-1+1/x >x-1.$

Answer (score 0):

Possibly correct but unreadable.

Consider
$$
\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}=x-\frac{x-1}{x^2+1}>x
$$
whenever $x>1$.

Comment: but you should consider the absolute value...

Comment: @mengdie1982 And so? For $x>0$, $\frac{x^3+1}{x^2+1}>0$.

Comment: but what if $x<0$?

Comment: @mengdie1982 You have to compute the limit at $\infty$, so it is not restrictive to assume $x>0$.